# Problem with hibernate request (Oracle)

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, oracle10g, ora-00923

i have a problem with my request, i don't understand why i have this error

> from keyword not found where expected

**my dao**

```
public List getAllDeclaration(String anneeEnCours) throws FiscaliteException {
    if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) 
    {
        LOGGER.debug("getAllDeclaration");
    }
    // Creation de la connexion
    Session session = getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    List allDeclaration = null;
    try{
        String query =  "FROM CalculIDF calculIDF " +
                "WHERE calculIDF.idCalculIDF.annee=:annee ";
        Query q = null;
        q = session.createQuery(query);
        q.setString("annee", anneeEnCours);

        allDeclaration =  q.list();
        session.flush();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage()+" "+e.getStackTrace());
    }
    return allDeclaration;
}
```

**Error in the console**

> 2010-08-19 15:01:47,962 ERROR
>   util.JDBCExceptionReporter
>   (JDBCExceptionReporter.java:72) -
>   ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found
>   where expected

Comment: can you post your conf. files.confirm DIALECT once it should be oracle's.

Comment: i think problem is in my mapping

Comment: resolved, it is my mapping was not consistent

Comment: Then either post the solution or delete the question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you use this for the query (adding the "as" keyword):

```
 String query =  "FROM CalculIDF as calculIDF " +
            "WHERE calculIDF.idCalculIDF.annee=:annee ";
```